# Javascript multiple actions at once

Tags: javascript, function, select

I have a function that I have create to display fruits and vegetables. The function is supposed to return several elements simultaneously, but I keep kitting a snag trying to return  values. My code is:

Can anyone see the error in my function?

```js
function fetchDetails() {
  var x = document.getElementById("food").value;
  var str = ""
  for (var color of colors) {
    str += "<option>" + item + "</option>"
  };
  var foodtype = {
    Apple || Orange || Banana: {
      foodname: 'Fruit',
      img: 'http://example.com/fruit.jpg',
      foodshort: "FRU",
      colors: ["Red", "Orange", "Green"]
    },
    Eggplants || Cucumber || Spinach: {
      foodname: 'Vegetable',
      img: 'http://example.com/vegetable.jpg',
      foodshort: "VEG",
      colors: ["Green", "Purple", "Red"]
    },
  };
  var f = foodtype[x];
  document.getElementById("foodname").innerHTML = f && f.foodname;
  document.getElementById("img").src = f && f.img;
  document.getElementById("foodshort").value = f && f.foodshort;
  document.getElementById("colors").innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="food" onkeyup="fetchDetails()">
<p id="foodname"></p>
<img id="img"></img>
<input type="text" id="foodshort">
<select id="colors"></select>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code to help us be able to read it more easily.

Comment: Also, please explain what your code does and how you want it to act differently? For one thing, I don't see where you are returning anything.

Comment: So `Apple || Orange || Banana` as the key of an object probably doesn't do what you're wanting it to. Not sure what you were after, so what was your intention there? To assign the same object to each of those keys?

Comment: syntax errors for json property colors which should be followed by ': ' instead of '='

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to edit the format after it has been posted, but the function is intended to return a specific <p> <input> <img> and <select> when a specific word - like Apple or Orange is entered into the "food" input field.

Comment: The pipes between elements || are intended to mean the data is returned with Apple OR Orange OR Banana is entered

Comment: Hopefully the reformatted code is a bit easier on the eyes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below mentioned JSON format and loop through the array and use the colors object and image to display

```
var foodtype = [{
item:['Apple', 'Orange','Banana'], 
foodname: 'Fruit',
img: 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg',
foodshort: "FRU",
colors : ["Red", "Orange", "Green"]
},
 {
item:['Eggplants' , 'Cucumber' , 'Spinach'],
foodname: 'Vegetable',
img: 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg',
foodshort: "VEG",
colors : ["Green", "Purple", "Red"]
},
];
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qxedOP

JS:

```
function fetchDetails() {
var x = document.getElementById("food").value;

var foodtype = [{
item:['Apple', 'Orange','Banana'], 
foodname: 'Fruit',
img: 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg',
foodshort: "FRU",
colors : ["Red", "Orange", "Green"]
},
 {
item:['Eggplants' , 'Cucumber' , 'Spinach'],
foodname: 'Vegetable',
img: 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg',
foodshort: "VEG",
colors : ["Green", "Purple", "Red"]
},
];

for(var i =0; i < foodtype.length; i++){
   if(foodtype[i].item.indexOf(x) != -1){
     var f = foodtype[i];
document.getElementById("foodname").innerHTML = f && f.foodname;
document.getElementById("img").src = f && f.img;
document.getElementById("foodshort").value = f && f.foodshort;
var str = ""
for (var color of f.colors) {
str += "<option>" + color + "</option>"
};
document.getElementById("colors").innerHTML = str;
   }
}

}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much. Your code works perfectly.

Comment: Do you know how to add the option title as the value to? e.g. <option value="Red">Red</option>?

Comment: "<option value='"+color+"'>" + color + "</option>"

Comment: That's great - I added that without a problem. It doesn't seem like those options are can be selected though? @Naga Sai A

Comment: @PhysicsIsRelativelyCool, didnt get , it displays colors in the dropdown and you will be able to select

Comment: I fixed the issue on my end. I had to remove the onchange element from the color select menu. It was running the funtion every time I selected and color and refreshed

Comment: I don't mean to pester you! But am I able to add a second string for another select option? str2? When I duplicate the var str = '' code is doesnt work! lol

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can change your object to something like,

```
<html>

<body><input type="text" id="food" onkeyup="fetchDetails()" value="Apple">
<p id="foodname"></p>
<img id="img"></img>
<input type="text" id="foodshort">
<select id="colors"></select>

<script>
function fetchDetails() {
  var x = document.getElementById("food").value;
  var str = ""
  for (var color of colors) {
    str += "<option>" + item + "</option>";
  };

  var foodtype = {
  Apple : {
      foodname: 'Fruit',
      img: 'http://example.com/fruit.jpg',
      foodshort: "FRU",
      colors : ["Red", "Orange", "Green"]
    },
     Orange:{
      foodname: 'Fruit',
      img: 'http://example.com/fruit.jpg',
      foodshort: "FRU",
      colors : ["Red", "Orange", "Green"]
    },
     Banana:{
      foodname: 'Fruit',
      img: 'http://example.com/fruit.jpg',
      foodshort: "FRU",
      colors : ["Red", "Orange", "Green"]
    },
    Eggplants : {
      foodname: 'Vegetable',
      img: 'http://example.com/vegetable.jpg',
      foodshort: "VEG",
      colors : ["Green", "Purple", "Red"]
    },
    Cucumber : {
      foodname: 'Vegetable',
      img: 'http://example.com/vegetable.jpg',
      foodshort: "VEG",
      colors : ["Green", "Purple", "Red"]
    },
    Spinach: {
      foodname: 'Vegetable',
      img: 'http://example.com/vegetable.jpg',
      foodshort: "VEG",
      colors : ["Green", "Purple", "Red"]
    }
  };

  f = foodtype[x];
  console.log(f);
  document.getElementById("foodname").innerHTML = f && f.foodname;
  document.getElementById("img").src = f && f.img;
  document.getElementById("foodshort").value = f && f.foodshort;
  document.getElementById("colors").innerHTML = str;
}
fetchDetails();
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

It should work then, or if you want to go with your approach, you can use this expand function

```
function expand(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
        var key = keys[i],
            subkeys = key.split(/,\s?/),
            target = obj[key];
        delete obj[key];
        subkeys.forEach(function(key) { obj[key] = target; })
    }
    return obj;
}
  var foodtype = {
  'Apple, Orange, Banana' : {
  foodname: 'Fruit',
  img: 'http://example.com/fruit.jpg',
  foodshort: "FRU",
  colors : ["Red", "Orange", "Green"]
},

'Eggplants, Cucumber, Spinach' : {
  foodname: 'Vegetable',
  img: 'http://example.com/vegetable.jpg',
  foodshort: "VEG",
  colors : ["Green", "Purple", "Red"]
}
```

};

```
  var expanded = expand(foodtype);

  f = expanded[x];
  console.log(f);
  document.getElementById("foodname").innerHTML = f && f.foodname;
  document.getElementById("img").src = f && f.img;
  document.getElementById("foodshort").value = f && f.foodshort;
  document.getElementById("colors").innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: Great code - thanks! Unfortunately the colors select field isn't responding to a change in value. Any ideas how I could fix that?

Comment: how are you binding an event?
I did this
<select id="colors" onchange="fetchDetails()"></select>
it does trigger when i change the value.
Also in the fetchdetails() function you have used a variable named "item" which is not defined. Is item = x?

Comment: I added onkeyup="fetchDetails()" to the "food" input field to cause all the other fields to be populated. Thanks for pointing that out, the item variable should be color.